# How is my MongoDB database able to work without starting it

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb

I'm using MongoDB, Node.js and Ubuntu 16.04 OS.

I set up MongoDB database from `mongo` CLI. I also communicated with it using node.js's mongodb library.

I thought I should start the database first (and start listening on the port) with `mongod` command.

But now I didn't start the database with `mongod` and still my communication from node.js towards database works fine.

Should mongod be run prior to communication with database, or is mongod process still alive from restart (I cannot find it listed in processes), or maybe my node.js code stores data in local variables that I haven't notice?

Comment: If your mongo shell works fine, then mongod server must be running. Likely,  it was started by ubuntu's process manager (upstart or whatever is  the current tool)

Comment: Yes mongo shell also works. OK, so mongod is then started by OS on boot time. I use System Monitor to check started processes. Why don't I see mongod there?

Answer (score 1):

check on your ubuntu:

```
ps aux | grep mongod
```

if you see a process  then it's running.
You can also write: `top`

With `top` you will see the current status of your system along with all the processes running.

With `ps au` you only see all process that are not attached to your [TTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tty_(unix))

Comment: OK. I see it there owner is mongodb instead of my user, and is only listed when using x flag. I found out why my System Monitor didn't show it, as the user of the process is mongodb and not my user.

Comment: @croraf: yes, that's why.

Comment: @croraf mongodb is the standard user when you install mongodb. There are ways to change the user though. I also updated the answer on why you don't see the process without the `x`.